# How to programmatically allocate a subclass of NSButton with a custom NSButtonCell?

Tags: objective-c, nsbutton, nsbuttoncell

I' m trying to create a subclass of `NSButton` thats use also a subclass of `NSButtonCell` but I can' t do that in code!

This is my NSButonCell subclass that's works well if I create the button in IB and set his cell class directly in IB:

```
#import "MyCustomCell.h"

@implementation MyCustomCell

- (void)drawImage:(NSImage*)image withFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView*)controlView
{
    NSGraphicsContext *ctx = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
    CGContextRef contextRef = [ctx graphicsPort];

    NSData *data = [image TIFFRepresentation];
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)data, NULL);
    if(source) {
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
        CFRelease(source);

        CGContextSaveGState(contextRef);
        {
            NSRect rect = NSOffsetRect(frame, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            CGFloat white = [self isHighlighted] ? 0.2f : 0.35f;
            CGContextClipToMask(contextRef, NSRectToCGRect(rect), imageRef);
            [[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:white alpha:1.0f] setFill];
            NSRectFill(rect);
        } 
        CGContextRestoreGState(contextRef);

        CGContextSaveGState(contextRef);
        {
            NSRect rect = frame;
            CGContextClipToMask(contextRef, NSRectToCGRect(rect), imageRef);
            [[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.1f alpha:1.0f] setFill];
            NSRectFill(rect);
        } 
        CGContextRestoreGState(contextRef);        

        CFRelease(imageRef);
    }
 }

 - (void)drawBezelWithFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)controlView
 {
    NSGraphicsContext *ctx = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];

    CGFloat roundedRadius = 3.0f;

    BOOL outer = YES;
    BOOL background = YES;
    BOOL stroke = YES;
    BOOL innerStroke = YES;

    if(outer) {
        [ctx saveGraphicsState];
        NSBezierPath *outerClip = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:frame   xRadius:roundedRadius yRadius:roundedRadius];
        [outerClip setClip];

        NSGradient *outerGradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithColorsAndLocations:
                                 [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.20f alpha:1.0f], 0.0f, 
                                 [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.21f alpha:1.0f], 1.0f, 
                                 nil];

        [outerGradient drawInRect:[outerClip bounds] angle:90.0f];
        [outerGradient release];
        [ctx restoreGraphicsState];
    }

    if(background) {
        [ctx saveGraphicsState];
        NSBezierPath *backgroundPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:NSInsetRect(frame, 2.0f, 2.0f) xRadius:roundedRadius yRadius:roundedRadius];
        [backgroundPath setClip];

        NSGradient *backgroundGradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithColorsAndLocations:
                                      [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.17f alpha:1.0f], 0.0f, 
                                      [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.20f alpha:1.0f], 0.12f, 
                                      [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.27f alpha:1.0f], 0.5f, 
                                      [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.30f alpha:1.0f], 0.5f, 
                                      [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.42f alpha:1.0f], 0.98f, 
                                      [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.50f alpha:1.0f], 1.0f, 
                                      nil];

        [backgroundGradient drawInRect:[backgroundPath bounds] angle:270.0f];
        [backgroundGradient release];
        [ctx restoreGraphicsState];
    }

    if(stroke) {
        [ctx saveGraphicsState];
        [[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.12f alpha:1.0f] setStroke];
        [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:NSInsetRect(frame, 1.5f, 1.5f) xRadius:roundedRadius yRadius:roundedRadius] stroke];
        [ctx restoreGraphicsState];
    }

    if(innerStroke) {
        [ctx saveGraphicsState];
        [[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:1.0f alpha:0.05f] setStroke];
        [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:NSInsetRect(frame, 2.5f, 2.5f) xRadius:roundedRadius yRadius:roundedRadius] stroke];
        [ctx restoreGraphicsState];        
    }

    if([self isHighlighted]) {
        [ctx saveGraphicsState];
        [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:NSInsetRect(frame, 2.0f, 2.0f) xRadius:roundedRadius yRadius:roundedRadius] setClip];
        [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.0f alpha:0.35] setFill];
        NSRectFillUsingOperation(frame, NSCompositeSourceOver);
        [ctx restoreGraphicsState];
    }
}

@end
```

I also create a custom `NSButton` sublclass that use this `NSButtonCell`

```
#import "myButton.h"
#import "MyCustomCell.h"

@implementation myButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self setCell:[[MyCustomCell alloc] init]];
        self.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"add"];

    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

But when I create this button in my view the look of the button is the default one and not the customized style of the `NSButtonCell` subclass. If I set the cell in IB all work great but not in code. Anyone have an idea to solve that problem? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried -initWithNibName:bundle: for MyCustomCell initialization in your code like [self setCell:[[MyCustomCell alloc] initinitWithNibName:@"nibName"  bundle:nil]]; ?

Comment: I don't want to use nib o xib. I wan' t to allocate all in code

Comment: When you set a breakpoint in your myButton class, does the `-initWithFrame:` get called?   This seems like it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, the `-initWithFrame:` in the myButton class is called. Something is wrong but I don' t understand what. For me it's a big problem to use a XIB at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand how to fix the problem.

It' s needed to set the bezel style on the button calling `setBezelStyle`. With this line of code all works great except for the fact that the image is upside-down.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the cellClass class method?

```
+ (Class)cellClass {
    return MyCustomCell.class;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried also to use the `cellClass` method but still don' t work! It seems that the only solution is to use a a XIB file but it' s a really strange situation: should be possible to do it by code.